# Focus/highlight selected text among other

Tags: highlighting

I want to focus/highlight part of text(marked or selected in some other way) as shown in the picture(selected texts stays as it was but other text is dimmed)

Maybe there is some way or some package to get such effect:
[image: Highlighted text]

Comment: Could you please clarify the question?  What is it you want to do?

Comment: I want to focus/highlight part of text(marked or selected in some other way) as shown in the picture(selected texts stays as it was but other text is dimmed)

Comment: Could you please edit the post itself to provide the additional clarification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Focus](https://github.com/larstvei/Focus) is what you’re looking for.

> Focus provides focus-mode that dims the text of surrounding sections,
>   similar to iA Writer's Focus Mode.

You can find it on MELPA, if you have it configured in your init file, via `M-x package-install focus`. Once installed, you can enable it with `M-x focus-mode`.

Comment: It's pretty much what I want, but I can't find proper extension for `thing-at-point`(which is used by Focus package for finding things to highlighting) for highlighting XML tags. Anyway thanks for fast feedback.

Comment: Focus already works with XML. Highlighting tags is a different issue.

Comment: Also, check the built-in `nxml-mode` for XML syntax highlighting.